# Defining a "minimum" function to return the minimum of a list using another function that returns the smaller of two numbers

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, unbound

```
(defun *smaller* (x y)
  ( if (> x y) y
        x))
(defun *minimum* (lst)
  (do ((numbers lst (cdr numbers))
       (result (car numbers) (*smaller* result (car numbers))))
      ((null numbers) result)))
```

LISP says that variable "numbers" in "minimum" function is an unbound one although I think I've bound it to "lst". What am I missing?

Comment: i know, that this one is possibly for education, but isn't it better to use `reduce`? just `(reduce #'*smaller* lst)` ?

Comment: also, using `*earmuffs*` in function names is counter idiomatic, since this style is commonly used for special vars.

Comment: thank you for the info I'm quite new to coding. And yes, this is an assignment for my uni course I'm not a comp sci student.

Answer (score 4):

`Do` binds in parallel.  The expression for the initial value of `result` is `(cdr numbers)`, and `numbers` is unbound there.  [`Do*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm) would work here.

Comment: Tysm I did not know about this. Still, when I use "do* instead of "do" lisp says that NIL' is not of the expected type `REAL'. Could u guys give me some suggestions on where I made mistakes, or maybe another way to think about this?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to this problem is to try and think about it inductively.

- an empty list has no minimum;
- if the list is not empty, its first element is a candidate minimum:

  - if the rest of the list is empty it's the answer
  - else the candidate minumum is the smaller of the current candidate and the first element of the list, and carry on through the rest of the list.

This translates very naturally into Lisp:

```
(defun smaller (x y)
  (if (< x y) x y))

(defun running-minimum (candidate tail)
  (if (null tail)
      candidate
    (running-minimum (smaller candidate (first tail)) (rest tail))))

(defun minimum (list)
  (when (null list)
    (error "?"))                        ;ed is the standard text editor
  (running-minimum (first list) (rest list)))
```

### Notes

For good, if now mostly historical, reasons, CL makes no guarantees that code like this will be turned into an iterative process.  Many implementations do so, but a conforming implementation need not, and even implementation which do so may not always do so, for instance in interpreted code or code compiled for ease of debugging.  So a `minimum` function like the above is not really very idiomatic CL, and is certainly not completely safe if the code is meant to be portable.

However that is not my goal in this answer: one of the important things that you should get from learning lisp, in my opinion, is the ability to think inductively about solving problems.  In other words to think about a class of problems which can be solved by starting from a simple base case and then steps which get from some general case closer to the base case, and then expressing this in code.  This is a very different approach to programming than the approach which is natural in more imperative languages, and once you understand it it's a very powerful way of thinking.

As someone whose first serious language was FORTRAN (in the days when that was the correct way of writing its name even!) I think that this inductive approach is very important, and it's that which I wanted to get across here.

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely another way to look at the problem

Comment: this is the cleanest, self-evidently correct code here (which probably should be reformulated as a `do`-based loop (4newbies: because there's supposedly no TCO guarantee in CL) but that's just some syntactical juggling). the lesson: **avoid `do*`-based loops at all costs** (4nb: coz, timing issues are tricky). I even had to spend my precious internet gold to dv one especially muddy and hacky code here.

Comment: @WillNess: I've appended a note to the answer (longer than the answer) explaining what I was trying to get across and that it's not perhaps very natural CL.  You're right that for production use it should be `do` (or `loop` if it was me).

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun smaller (x y)
  "returns the smaller number"
  (if (> x y)
      y
    x))

(defun minimum (list)
  "returns the smallest number of a list"
  (do* ((numbers list (rest numbers))
        (result
         (first numbers)
         (if numbers
             (smaller result (first numbers))
           result)))
       ((null numbers) result)))
```

Comment: sorry, but this is unbearably hacky and muddy for my tastes. proving its correctness could be an exercise at some university course. had to dv. :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as pointed above, you should use `do*` instead of `do`, in order to bind the variables sequentially.
Second, you are testing `(null numbers)` to end the loop. However, when only one element is left to process, `numbers` is not nil but then it becomes `(cdr numbers)` which is nil. This nil value is what is being passed to `*smaller*` as second argument, and that's why you get the error message. To avoid this, you should test for `(null (cdr numbers))` instead:

```
(defun *smaller* (x y)
  ( if (> x y) y
        x))
(defun *minimum* (lst)
  (do* ((numbers lst (cdr numbers))
       (result (car numbers) (*smaller* result (car numbers))))
      ((null (cdr numbers)) result)))
```

This exits the loop when there is only one item left in the list.

Comment: Don't name functions as `*name*`. That convention is reserved for special variables.