# Attempting to define a function that provides the minimum integer in a list of numbers SPECIFICALLY using do loops (not do* or dolist, etc.)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, do-loops

I have an assignment for class specifically testing our understanding of do, asking to define a function to produce the minimum of a list of numbers. We are asked to also use a secondary function ("smaller") to do so.

I have no previous experience coding, and am forced to stay within the boundaries of do; I've been reading up on the issue as much as I can, but almost everything I find just suggests using other methods (do*, COND, etc.).

I defined a simple "smaller" as:

```
(defun smaller (x y)
  (if (< x y) x y))
```

I then approached the problem as such:

```
(defun minimum (lst)
  "(lst)
Returns the minimum of a list of numbers."
  (do ((numbers lst (cdr numbers))
       (min (car numbers) (smaller min (cadr numbers))))
      ((null numbers) min)))
```

I feel there's an issue where the "smaller" function can't be applied on the first loop (feedback about this would be great), otherwise my immediate issue is getting an error of: "UNBOUND-VARIABLE" for the variable "NUMBERS". I am not sure which 'area' is causing the confusion: if I have poorly formatted the do loop entirely, or if one of the second/third/etc. "numbers" is causing an issue.

Can someone provide some feedback? -- again keeping in mind that we are limited specifically to simple do loops, and that I definitely don't have a perfect understanding of what I've already got down.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: This question has already been answered here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920951/defining-a-minimum-function-to-return-the-minimum-of-a-list-using-another-func/59926913#59926913)

Answer (score 0):

`Do` binds in parallel, so `numbers` is not bound when `min` is first bound.  You could fix that by using `(car lst)` instead of `(car numbers)` there.

You need to fix the end condition then: `(cadr numbers)` is `nil` on the last iteration, you need to stop before that.

For better readability, I'd suggest to use `first` and `second` instead of `car` and `cadr` here.

Comment: Thanks! The first part especially really cleared up the sequential problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could still refer to `numbers` as long as you used `do*`, which is a sequentially binding variant of `do`. Then you'd have to use `car` instead of `cadr` - you're now picking the first number from an already reduced list. And you'd need to modify your end condition to avoid calling `smaller` with a `NIL` argument - you should be able to figure this out easily.